# Selenium unable to run on eclipse

Tags: selenium

Hi I am new to Selenium and trying a automation on a web form through it in eclipse. But when I execute my code it gets terminated 
Here is my code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\selenium\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.53.1\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new `InternetExplorerDriver();


driver.get("http://example.com");


    }

}
```

here is what i get on console

```
 testing US7ASCII against <abc>
    PASSED LOSSY
testing US7ASCII against <ab?c>
    PASSED LOSSY
testing US7ASCII against <XYZ>
    PASSED LOSSY
testing US7ASCII against <longlonglonglong...>
    PASSED LOSSY
testing WE8ISO8859P1 against <abc>
    PASSED LOSSY
testing WE8ISO8859P1 against <ab?c>
    PASSED LOSSY
testing WE8ISO8859P1 against <XYZ>
    PASSED LOSSY
testing WE8ISO8859P1 against <longlonglonglong...>
    PASSED LOSSY
testing AL24UTFFSS against <abc>
    PASSED 
testing AL24UTFFSS against <ab?c>
    PASSED 
testing AL24UTFFSS against <XYZ>
    PASSED 
testing AL24UTFFSS against <longlonglonglong...>
    PASSED 
testing UTF8 against <abc>
    PASSED 
testing UTF8 against <ab?c>
    PASSED 
testing UTF8 against <XYZ>
    PASSED 
testing UTF8 against <longlonglonglong...>
    PASSED
```

Application gets terminated as soon as I run it. Please help dont know where is the issue

Comment: Did you setup configuration for running IE webdriver?
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Answer (score 0):

The Log shows irrelevant to selenium code, seems it is running some JDBC program.

best way to run selenium code in eclipse, Just right-click on code, select RunAs, click on java application.

post the output...